# How to get a local HTML File's submit Data on the IPad

Tags: html, objective-c, ipad, post, submit

Essentially, I have a dynamically generated local HTML form that I would like to be able to get information from.  Is there any way to POST my data to another local file in the resources folder of my IPad application so I can actually parse and save it?

My problem is this form will be used in areas with no internet so I need to be able to save it locally.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method in your `UIWebViewDelegate` and pull out the form data from the `NSURLRequest` and save it to a local file or whatever else you need to do with it.

Comment: This should work. Thanks a lot.  I wasn't aware you could check for certain conditions before loading a page.